# Remove Content from on top of Shoutem ui NavigationBar

Tags: react-native, shoutem

When I use the Shoutem UI NavigationBar the content after is on top of the navigationbar. How can I move it down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently this pattern seems to be the best option

```
<Screen
                style={{ paddingTop: 70 }}
            >
                <NavigationBar
                    centerComponent={<Title>Title</Title>}
                />
                <Title>Content now below NavigationBar</Title>
            </Screen>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `inline` `styleName` will resolve this issue as described in the [docs](https://shoutem.github.io/docs/ui-toolkit/components/navigation-bar#style-names).

From the docs:

> - **inline**: forces relative positioning of `NavigationBar` component, allowing component to be used inline with other components,
>     i.e. `ListView`, without its content overlapping `NavigationBar`

Example:

```
<NavigationBar
  styleName="inline"
  title="My Title"
/>

<Button>
  <Text>My text.</Text>
</Button>
```

Comment: Hi, inline doesn't work properly when rotating the device as documented in open issue https://github.com/shoutem/ui/issues/247, i added the question and answer to stackoverflow as i wanted to help people avoid frustration